# How to convert a 3 digit code into a Date range across 2 columns in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column containing a 3 digit code that relates to a time period. The first 2 digits are the year and the third the quarter. EG: 213 = 2021 Q3. Ideally, I would like to create 2 new columns In Google Big Query as a start_date and end_date for that period.

EG: 213 would become:

start_date | end_date

01/07/2021 | 30/09/2021

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select parse_date('%y%Q', '' || code) as start_date , 
  last_day(parse_date('%y%Q', '' || code) + 70) as end_date
from table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: You can state QUARTER in LAST_DAY() function in order to avoid adding natural days. Would look like: LAST_DAY(PARSE_DATE('%y%Q', '' || code), QUARTER)

Comment: have you tried it with February in between - wanted to avoid risk as I remember  - there were reports that behavior in such cases is not as expected  :o) try and let us know.